# how can I change sentence not using 得?

Tags: grammar

my question is

大声回答 can be changed to 回答得大声 ?

So if I can make other sentences using V+de (得)+Adj become Adj+V ?

Answer (score 3):

得(去声) refers to 'must,have to '
回答得大声  回答 is V.  and 大声 is Adj. So you can make other sentences using V+de (得)+Adj become Adj+V ,**but**,a point need to notice, for another example,教室得打扫 and 打扫教室 ,though it is can be exchange ,but their means are little difference, the first one has another meaning that the classroom is dirty and need to clean.

In addition, if the sentence is pronoun+得+ V ,in this condition,you can't exchange like before,for example: 我得去游泳 ,we can't say 游泳我.

Comment: Agree with your answer, but I would like to point out that, 得 used in '教室得打扫' and '回答得大声' is slightly different.  教室得打扫 - classroom 'needs' to be cleaned.   回答得大声 - answered 'with' loud(ly voice).

Comment: Oh,thanks for pointing out this,I did't pay attention to it before.

Answer (score 0):

according to iciba and other web sources 大叫、大醉 、大吼（一声 ）、小声 work similarly：高兴得大叫、大叫一声；喝得大醉，大醉上床（note ２ syllables （prosodic feature），i。e。大醉喝 may be unacceptable），气得大吼一声，大吼一声发出了口令；笛子怎样才能吹得小声、小声嘀咕什么、小声问：“你有烟
吗？＂

In the given example 回答得大声 得 is used to link 大声 as a complement of manner，in 大声回答， 大声 functions as adverbial of manner （necessarily before the verb）。 大叫、大吼（一声 ）、小声 can be used similarly，on the other hand 大醉 represents a consequential state，which can occur as complement linked by 得，or occur as adverbial of manner （大醉上床）。Because 大醉 represents the consequential state there is another reason why ＊大醉喝 may be unacceptable 。

Comment: regarding issues raised above about 大醉，web examples seem to confirm unacceptability of 大醉喝 （one syllable verb following ２－syllable adverbial）while e。g。大醉喝下（两瓶白酒）is acceptable。 Also note that 得 used to link complements of manner or consequential state is often replaced by 个， e。g。喝个大醉....喝死拉倒！